# Poor display quality with pdf-tools after system update

Tags: pdf-tools

I am using manjaro operating system. After the last system update I noticed a somewhat annoying  thing when viewing pdf files in emacs with pdf-tools. The rendering quality become poor and the image is blurry. Does anyone has a suggestion on how to fix this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just for clarity, you are definitely still seeing a buffer rendered by `pdf-tools`? Check that it's not actually the default `doc-view-mode` handler for PDFs in Emacs.

Comment: @phils yes I think so since I can see the pdf-tools menu when the buffer window is activated!

Comment: @phils The problem is with emacs 27. Solved by downgrading to emacs 26